# Listbox binding - delayed by one source

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-7

hey. I'm trying to maintain an MVVM model, but am tripping up somewhere when trying to bind to a listbox. The first time I run the application, I set `ItemCatalog` (ObservableCollection) to be a certain ObservableCollection list. The listbox is empty, but if I try again it works. However, there is a lag between the datasource and the displayed data. For example,

I load the app -> set source to `X` -> Listbox is empty

I now set source to `Y` -> Listbox displays `X`

I set source to `Z` -> Listbox displays `Y` etc..

This, to me, implies the binding is working but I can't figure out why it's lagging by one.

My XAML looks like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCatalog}">
       <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ref}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Foreground="Black" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Foreground="Black" />
             </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the ViewModel, the value of `ItemCatalog` is based on whichever button the user pressed (`X`,`Y`,`Z`), which are all stored in a static variable. Is there a reason there's a delay, or a way to force it to rebind to the latest `ItemCatalog` value?

If I remove the binding from the XAML and set the listbox source straight from the code-behind, it works perfectly. However, I want to try and maintain the XAML coding. I'm new to MVVM so I might be doing this the wrong way round. thanks

EDIT - extra code

The code is changed in the OnNavigatedTo method

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {


            if (NavigationContext.QueryString["Category"].ToString() == "House")
            {
                _categoryType = Models.House;

            }
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString["Category"].ToString() == "Car")
            {
                _categoryType = Models.Car;

            }

            MyViewModel.LoadNewData(_categoryType);


            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }
```

`LoadNewData` method just sets the static variable based on the parameter passed.

```
   ItemCatalog = App.CarCatalog;
```

Essentially, I need to rebind after the page has loaded, via XAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At guess (since there still isn't really enough code to go on) your ViewModel is raising a property change even before the field backing `ItemCatalog` is actually assigned. Something like:-

```
 ObservableCollection<Stuff> _ItemCatalog;
 ObservableCollection<Stuff> ItemCatalog 
 {

    get { retutn _ItemCatalog; }
    set
    {
       PropertyChanged("ItemCatalog");
       _ItemCatalog = value;
    }
 }
```

This might result in the behaviour you describe.

Comment: That's a great shot in the dark! :D I moved the NotifyPropertyChange method and in the View, I put the DataContext within the `PropertChanged` event of the ViewModel. I thought the DataContext would only need to be set the once, but it seems that I had to set it everytime the PropertyChange event is raised. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any code on where you change source from X to y but I would assume from the explained behavior that the data binding on your view is being interpreted before that change is taking place.

Comment: Is ItemCatalog an ObservableCollection?

Comment: I managed to solve it (check accepted answer), but yes, ItemCatalog is an ObservableCollection.